# asp datalist anyone can explain in detail

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am still new to asp.net. I have some question that I would like to ask and I came from php and c++.

First question. Inside html or aspx. If I want to write c# code, normally <% %> should work but what is the different between the bottom 3.

```
<% %>
<%@ 
<%# %>
```

Container.DataItem came from DataSource from Datalist.

Secondly, the bottom of the code is giving me error. Thus I would like to have a give explanation. It seem legal to me in c++. Error Invalid arguement? From msdn Eval should return object or string

```
<div class="newPanel">
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList_News" runat="server" CssClass="newPanel">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="news"></div>

          <div id="news_space" runat="server" visible="<%# DisplaySpace(System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "product_id")); %>"></div>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
</div>


public partial class CommonCx_captcha_displaynews : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DataList_News.DataSource = MySqlManager.ExecuteSelectCommand("select * from news;");
      DataList_News.DataBind();
    }

    public bool DisplaySpace(System.String id)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These are called inline server tags, *basically* they are used for;

```
<% %>     -- For embeding a code block
<%@ %>    -- For defining a page directive
<%# %>    -- For data binding 
<%= %>    -- For accessing a variable or return value of a method
<%$ %>    -- For accessing AppSettings
<%-- --%> -- For commenting
```

These two links have good examples with exact definitions/syntax. **[Link1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)** and **[Link2](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx)**

For the second question, I think this would be enough

```
visible='<%# DisplaySpace(Eval("product_id")) %>'
```

Comment: So If I called my own function. for example visible= " .... all the code ", I should use <%= %> instead of <%# %>?

Comment: Last by not least, why <%# %> why we are not allow put semi-colon at the end of Eval? We are calling a function?

Comment: In this case NO because you are inside a DataList and should use data binding syntax with `#`.

Comment: I think that is the syntax tbh.

Answer (score 0):

your method expect string, so convert sending parameter to string

```
visible = '<%# DisplaySpace(System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "product_id").ToString())%>'
```

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Label_news" runat="server" Text="<%# System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "product_id"); %>"></asp:Label>   and what is  The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: In short what is server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Sorry for asking weird question. but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck.aspx  It said return system.string

Comment: So by default Eval will return me a string. Thus I don't need to do a conversion. Unless System.string and string is two different type which do not make sense lol.

Answer (score 0):

Anwsearing your questions:

1) In line Server Tags are used to write server code into the markup:

```
<%= %> - is used to resolve an expression and return its value into the block.
<%@ %> - attributes used by the ASP.NET page parser and compiler.
<%$ %> - expression sintax to reuse code in the markup.
<%# %> - data binding  syntax
```

2) You must use single quotes surrounding C# code in the aspx, that's why you get the error:

```
'<%# DisplaySpace(System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "product_id")); %>'
```